# Apache Nifi Custom Processor dependency on another processor

Tags: apache-nifi

As per my requirement I need to create a Nifi custom processor which will do structuring of message and then write to Splunk.

I am following below link for creating custom processor but not clear on how to make use of invokeHttpProcessor/putSplunk processor within custom processor code. Any suggestion is appreciated

https://help.syncfusion.com/data-integration/how-to/create-a-custom-processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the actual processor implementations like InvokeHttp and PutSplunk are not meant to be subclassed as-is, if there is code that should be available for reuse among processors, please feel free to reach out to the community (via [mailing list](https://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html) for example) and we can discuss moving such code out to an API.

In the meantime, I'm not sure it would work to put the implementation NAR as a parent of the custom processor NAR but you can try that, it perhaps will let you subclass the implementations, but it is not recommended.

An alternative is to just copy the code from the processor(s) you want and use that duplicate code directly in your custom processor. There are some maintainability changes there of course, but if you encapsulate your custom processor away from the duplicated NiFi processor, you would just need to keep an eye out for any changes made to the NiFi processor and update your copy accordingly.